# How to force ggplot2 to show axis tick labels smaller than 10^-100 on log-scale axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I need to show on graph points which have extremely small values, i.e. smaller than 10^-100. Unfortunately, 'ggplot' stops showing tick labels at that value. E.g.

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)
data <- data.frame(x =10^-(seq(0,250,by=20)),y= 10^-(seq(250,0,by=-20)))
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_log10(labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                limits = c(10^-300,1),
                breaks = 10^(seq(-300,0,by = 20)))+
  scale_y_log10(labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                limits = c(10^-300,1),
                breaks = 10^(seq(-300,0,by = 20)))+
  theme_classic()
```

Which results in a following graph:
[Tick labels end at 10^-100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i969j.jpg)

As you see I tried setting limits, and manually set the tick (`brakes` option). No effect though. Google search and SO search yielded no answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd little bug; I'm also unable to make a log10 scale use any breaks smaller than 10^-100, even though double precision floats can get down to 2.2e-308.

I don't know why, but this workaround using `scales::pseudo_log_trans` works. It's a transform that blends a linear scale up to around +/- the `sigma` parameter with a log scale beyond. It's able to handle your example fine, and the distortion happens way off screen (around 1e-308).

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)
data <- data.frame(x =10^-(seq(0,250,by=20)),y= 10^-(seq(250,0,by=-20)))
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = .Machine$double.xmin),
                     breaks = 10^(seq(-300,0,by = 20))) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = .Machine$double.xmin),
                     breaks = 10^(seq(-300,0,by = 20))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]